# How do I work with an Amf ByteArray string in php?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, amf, amfphp

I have what I *think* is a ByteArray. When using `urlencode` on the string, I get this data...

```
%0A%82%03%01%11SaleDate%0DToYear%0DYardId%15BuyNowOnly%0BState%0BModel%0FStockId%11FromYear%11FullText%13Inventory%11Category%09Make%0FOrderBy%1DOrderDirection%0FPageNum%11PageSize%01%01%06%05-1%02%06%01%01%01%01%06%0F1024187%06%09Sale%01%01%06%13RunNumber%06%07Asc%04%01%04d
```

I am looking at the php function unpack, and trying `unpack('c4char/Xstr/...')` where X is a, A, h, H to try to pull the "SaleDate" string out, but I can't get it to work.

Probably the completely wrong approach. Do I need to write a custom unpacker of some sort?

I'm not even sure what I'm dealing with here, it's the output from a flash file, so I think it's an Amf "ByteArray" but I'm at a loss as to how to parse it.

Looking for even just a direction to start hunting for how to manipulate/parse/rebuild something like this. Ultimately I'd love to be able to run it through a function, get an associative array, change a few values, repack it, and send it on it's merry way.

I think it's [AMF3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format) and this is the data in the messages part.

I guess if there's one "main" question, how do I manipulate that string of data simply and safely?

Thanks for any leads.

Comment: Hi Dustin, I believe this is just a URL encoded String that you're sending to the PHP instead of actual AMF however if you google for AMFPHP http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_AMFPHP___Flex_4_demo-16508.html you may also want to consider using Zend which is a PHP framework (and I believe includes AMFPHP) you'd have to Google for details on setup/configuration but once setup this creates an easy means to serialize/de-serialize objects from PHP objects to AS3 objects (just need to set an _explicitType in the PHP object that corresponds to the fully qualified name of the AS3 Object)

Comment: Actually, as I mentioned, I "urlencoded" it so that it would display the bytes. The bytes in their unencoded form are just whitespace since they're not real characters. And yes, I've looked at Zend_AMF and AmfPHP, and if you look in `Amfphp_Core_Amf_Types_ByteArray` all they do is hold the string, I couldn't find anything to manipulate the string. I'm not sending data "to" php, this is the data I have in php and I'm trying to figure out how to either create this string, or manipulate it safely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this appears to be a proprietary encoding method specific to the vendor. They use a "Byte Array" to allow greater flexibility of the payload. There isn't an easy way to work with this, without completely reverse engineering their encoding and decoding algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of AMF deserializers out there that are open source, for simplicity sake, would probably make a lot of sense to not roll your own here, even though AMF3 is fairly simple.

I came across this link on github which looks promising:

https://github.com/silexlabs/amfphp-2.0

You probably don't want to roll the whole framework, but can probably roll this:

[/core/amf/Deserializer.php](https://github.com/silexlabs/amfphp-2.0/blob/master/Amfphp/Core/Amf/Deserializer.php)

[/core/amf/Serializer.php](https://github.com/silexlabs/amfphp-2.0/blob/master/Amfphp/Core/Amf/Serializer.php)

Comment: Yea, I have that, and this is the deserialized result. The deserializer returns a `Amfphp_Core_Amf_Packet` and in the packet are headers and messages. In the messages is one message with a `Amfphp_Core_Amf_Types_ByteArray` which only has the above string stored in a variable. There's no manipulation functions or further decoding that I can see. This is already deserialized from the original AMF packet. Just trying to figure out how to manipulate it now.

Comment: hmm, have you tried deserializing the bytearray again?  Yeah, this definitely looks like an amf3 packet, the bytearray would be another amf3 packet.

Comment: I do see your issue though, all these deserializers have all this extra code to deal with class referencing and such, and you just want a simple object.  Will look around some more, this has to exist somewhere

Comment: Sorry for the delay, lost power from the east coast storm. Anyways, yea I've tried deserializing it again, but it's not the same format as an AMF packet. It looks like something different. I'm thinking it's a custom pack/unpack, but I've had no luck figuring it out.

Comment: yeah you might be right.  Actually, it look like it might be something like CSV, with funky delimiters (they look like field identifiers, but I can't see a common occurrence)  Doesn't look like they map to amf3 identifiers.